# How to return json object from jsp to angularjs ajax http.get?

Tags: json, angularjs, jsp

When I run the jsp file I get [{"USRNM":"sahar","USRPWD":"password"}] which is correct but when I run html I cant display the data and when I alert it I get the data inside html tag while I tried with json file which alerts data in the form of [object object].please help me to find out what I am doing wrong.

jsp:

```
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select UsrNm,UsrPwd from dbo.tblUsr"); 


    ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();

    int numberOfColumns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    //List <JSONObject> jsonArray = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
      List <String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=1;i<=numberOfColumns;i++) {
        columnNames.add(rsMetaData.getColumnName(i).toUpperCase());
    } 
     while(rs.next()) {
         JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
         for(int i=1;i<=numberOfColumns;i++) {
            String key = columnNames.get(i - 1);
            Object value = rs.getObject(i);
            obj.put(key, value);
         }

    jsonArray.add(obj);
     }

     //response.setContentType("application/json");
       // response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
       response.getWriter().write(jsonArray.toString());
```

html:

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

   <table>
   <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
   <td>{{ x.USRNM}}</td>
   <td>{{ x.USRPWD}}</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   </div>

   <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("newjsp2.jsp")
              .success(function (response) {
              // alert(JSON.stringify(response));
              alert(response);
              $scope.names = response;
        }).error(function(response,status,headers,config){
              alert('cannot find resource');
              console.log(response);
              console.log(status);
              console.log(headers);
              console.log(confiq);
         }); 
   });
   </script>
```

Comment: What does alert(response); return to you in $http.get("newjsp2.jsp").success()

Comment: It returns: [{"USRNM":"sahar","USRPWD":"password"}] <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <title>jsp page</title></head><body></body></html>

Comment: When I use json file instead of jsp, the alert returns [object object] So I guess the jsp should also return in the form of object while it returns the data and html tags together. but im not sure this is the problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code as I think the data returned from your JSP is in string format, so you need to convert it to JSON format before using in Angular JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
       $http.get("newjsp2.jsp").success(function (response) {
          $scope.names = JSON.parse(response);
      })
     .error(function(response,status,headers,config){
            alert('cannot find resource');
     }); 
  });
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt display anything.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using response.getWritter.... I replaced 3 lines and remove html tags in jsp file so now it works properly :)

```
   // response.setContentType("json");
      // response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   //response.getWriter().write(jsonArray.toString());

       //These 3 lines
       PrintWriter out1 = response.getWriter();
        out1.print(jsonArray);
        out1.flush();
```